# Django-Filer Canonical URLS not working properly (Page not Found)

Tags: python, django, django-urls, pythonanywhere, django-filer

I am using Django-Filer in my admin on a Django web project which is hosted in PythonAnywhere. I have gone through the installation instructions but I am having trouble accessing the canonical urls the Filer makes for each file. It seems I am being directed to an extended url that Filer.urls is not recognizing (the non-canonical part starts at /filer-public/; this is a directory that is being created and storing my files on the separate PythonAnywhere file directory).

Is there an error in my urls syntax? An error in my views.canonical? I am unsure of why plugging in the exact canonical url redirects me to this extended version of the url.

Python: 3.7
Django: 2.2

**Canonical URL:
/filer/sharing/1560887480/39/**

**ERROR / DEBUGGING SCREEN**

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://www.mywebsite.com/filer/sharing/1560887480/39/filer_public/36/ea/36ea58a8-f59c-41ad-9d1f-00a976603eb1/big1.jpg

Using the URLconf defined in mywebsitesite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    ^filer/ sharing/(?P<uploaded_at>[0-9]+)/(?P<file_id>[0-9]+)/$ [name='canonical']

The current path, filer/sharing/1560887480/39/filer_public/36/ea/36ea58a8-f59c-41ad-9d1f-00a976603eb1/big1.jpg, didn't match any of these.
```

**APP URLS: /mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/filer/urls.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import

from django.conf.urls import url

from . import settings as filer_settings
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(
        filer_settings.FILER_CANONICAL_URL + r'(?P<uploaded_at>[0-9]+)/(?P<file_id>[0-9]+)/$',  # flake8: noqa
        views.canonical,
        name='canonical'
    ),
]
```

**APP VIEWS: /mywebsite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/filer/VIEWS.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect

from .models import File


def canonical(request, uploaded_at, file_id):
    """
    Redirect to the current url of a public file
    """
    filer_file = get_object_or_404(File, pk=file_id, is_public=True)
    if (not filer_file.file or int(uploaded_at) != filer_file.canonical_time):
        raise Http404('No %s matches the given query.' % File._meta.object_name)
    return redirect(filer_file.url)
```

**BASE URLS: /home/mywebsite/mywebsite/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from quotes.views import Register

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    url(r'^filer/', include('filer.urls')),
]
```

**BASE SETTINGS: /home/mywebsite/mywebsite/settings.py**

```
FILER_CANONICAL_URL = 'sharing/'
```

Comment: I don't know Django-Filter, but perhaps you could try changing `FILER_CANONICAL_URL` to `'/sharing/'` with a leading slash and see if that helps?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the canonical url to work by configuring the static and media root in my urls and settings files, as shown below.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^filer/', include('filer.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.environ.get('FILER_MEDIA_ROOT', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'))

MEDIA_URL = '/home/mywebsite/media/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by not including the *filer.urls* but rather specifying the url pattern directly in my projects *urls.py* file.

Django 3.1.7

django-filer 2.1.2

**/myproject/myproject/urls.py**:

```
...
from filer import views as filer_views
from .settings import FILER_CANONICAL_URL
...

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^filer/'+FILER_CANONICAL_URL+r'/(?P<uploaded_at>[0-9]+)/(?P<file_id>[0-9]+)/$',
      filer_views.canonical,
      name='canonical'),
  ...,
]
```

**/myproject/myproject/settings.py**

```
...
FILER_CANONICAL_URL = 'somefolder/'
```

However I'm still not sure where the extra space was coming from in the first place - the filer urls.py and settings.py look fine as far as I can tell.