# Django-filer problem when retrieve uploaded image in Django admin interface or any http|s request

Tags: django, django-filter, django-media

I'm a noob in Django framework, sorry for misunderstanding in some concepts.
Currently, I'm trying to set up a Django app with `django-filer`. Django filer was installed commonly and migrations were done according to documentation. The installed apps list was updated with filer, mptt, and easy_thumbnails. The allowed host was updated with the IP of the host, `debug` flag was set to true and timezones and language code were also updated, as shown below. According to documentation, that's all for a basic setup of Django filer.

```
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["192.168.230.98"]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'filer',
    'mptt',
    'easy_thumbnails'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'filerTest.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'filerTest.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

USE_I18N = True
USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Two images were uploaded through the Django admin interface.  After images are upload, the Django admin interface can't retrieve they. Chrome development console showed a 404 error, like if images were not stored. When I check if images were stored, They are in a random names subfolder in the filer_public and file_public_thumbnails directories, according to other forums, this is the expectable behavior.

I try to set static_url parameter in settings.py. However, it's only possible to set one path. Then, I should choose between filer_public or filer_public_thumbnails or static directories to serve static files. This is not a good approach.

[image: Django admin not retrieve image]

[image: Error from Django when try to expand or open image in a separate window]

Some idea about what step or error I done during Django filer setup?

Comment: Did you add the Django-filer urls to your project? See https://django-filer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#canonical-urls

Comment: Yes, I add to urlpatterns. 

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^filer/', include('filer.urls'))
]

Comment: But I have a doubt, django-filer should create a directory filer? 
Where is filer.urls file?

Comment: https://github.com/django-cms/django-filer/blob/master/filer/urls.py

Comment: URL should be `/filer/canonical/<uploaded_at>/<file_id>`

Comment: But URL in the second image is generated by Django, I can't modify this URL. With respect to URL filer file, the directory filer should be created by filer during installation or migration? I don't have this directory on my project. The documentation doesn't show specifications about this directory or how create it.

Comment: After adding the filer folder and urls.py file, the problem persists yet.

Comment: This might answer your question- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56743492/9638991

Comment: you're right. Add MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL to settings.py fixed the problem. Thanks a lot !!!
Could you put the solution in an Answer to approve your solution? please?

Comment: We could probably just mark this question as a duplicate of the one I linked, what do you think?

Comment: If this is the right way. I don't have any problem with that (Y)